# How can I use live view while tethering a Nikon D810 to LightRoom 5 CC?

Tags: nikon, lightroom, tethering, nikon-d810

My camera is a Nikon D810. I have the Adobe Creative Cloud suite and haven't updated it for a while, but my Lightroom version is 5.

My camera came with a cable, one side was a HDMI I think that I connected to port of the camera and the other side was a USB cable that I connected to the laptop and opened Lightroom, and was able to take pictures with the viewfinder of the camera and they showed up but I can not get LiveView of the camera to turn on and use that instead of viewfinder.

I want LiveView so I can zoom in on my focus point and exactly see if I am tack sharp or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lightroom don't support tethering with live view for Nikon cameras. If you want to use tethering with live view you need a another application like [Camera Control Pro](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Imaging-Software/Camera-Control-Pro-2---Full-Version-(Boxed).html), [ControlMyNikon](http://www.controlmynikon.com/) or a freeware [digiCamControl](http://digicamcontrol.com/) or any similar application.

You can use external application with lightroom with no problem if you activate the [Auto Import](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/import-photos-automatically.html) feature

Comment: Do you have a source for that information? I was unable to find one via Adobe so I wonder if you did. I found it odd that the compatibility KB from Adobe states the "notes" for Nikon cameras but does not list anything about live view: https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support.html

Comment: digiCamControl is amazing!! Loved it for Nikon D810. Would loved it more if there were a Mac version too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Lightroom Version 5.0?

If so you need to upgrade to at least 5.7.

This website lists the minimum version required for the D810:
https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support.html

I'm not sure if possibly your issue is that you have a version older than 5.7 and that is causing live view to not work. It is possible that live view is not a feature of the Nikon SDK.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it is 5.7.1 but I will update it, Credit card I had registered Adobe CC was expired and didn't bother updating it until now.

Answer (score 0):

you can see live view with the Nikon camera control Pro 2
is Nikon software support all the Nikon cameras and you can set all the camera stting from your computer
is more setting and control for your camera
but i am using it only for live setting and viewing because Lightroom they dont have this features

Answer (score 0):

[Sofortbild](http://www.sofortbildapp.com/) (free Mac software) works for me. The Nikon D810 is in the [supported camera list](http://www.sofortbildapp.com/support/faqs/supported-cameras-sofortbild-15/):

> FX (full frame) format models
> Nikon D3, D3S, D3x
> Nikon D4, D4S
> Nikon D5
> Nikon D300, D300S
> Nikon D600, D610
> Nikon D700, D750
> Nikon D800, D800E
> **Nikon D810**, D810A
> Nikon Df

I switch between Lightroom and Sofortbild if I need liveview during tethered shooting.